# How to access outside folders when running?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

When my application is running (server: run), I want to access a folder outside my project directory.

I use Symfony 4 and PHP7. I have this architecture :

- `/ressources`
- `/symfony_project`
- `/other_folder`

And I would like to render an image from `/ressources` like `../ressources/myimage.png`.

I am stucked with this url `http://127.0.0.1/ressources/myimage.png` because `127.0.0.1` = `/symfony_project`. So it is not working.

Do I have to use a symlink? How do I do that?

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Can you create a symlink between /resources and the public directory of your symfony project?

Comment: How do I dow that?

Comment: Look at this to find out how: https://askubuntu.com/a/56340

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: I created it as an answer for other people.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible without possibly over-engineering a solution. I think the easiest solution is creating a symlink between your directory of resources and the public Symfony folder.

Just be cautious when doing this as you could expose things you may not want to.

You can create a symlink link like this:

```
ln -s /opt/foo /usr/bin/bar
```

You can see a better explanation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link/56340#56340).

Comment: I did it and it worked great! but it copied all the files in the public folder. I thought it will create like an "invisible" link. Is the copy normal or is there a solution to avoid that? Thanks